# How to get the default extension for a given content type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the variable `content_type = "application/pdf"` that can also include any other mime type.

How can I get the default extension for the content type?

I have currently two solutions, which seem very "complicated".

**Hack the string**

```
content_type.split("/")[1]
```

**Use MIME::Types**

```
  require 'mime/types'
  MIME::Types[content_type].first.extensions.first
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Used your second solution, worked like a charm. By the way, in rails app I did not need to require mime/types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second solution with the mime type is the solution, which you should choose. There are several reasons for that:

- The second solution is exactly designed for your use case
- `Hack the string` could be inconsistent or return unexpected results (think about `application/postscript` has the extension `eps`!)
- Please consider, that we probably can't say, that every mime type has it's default extension. For example: who has defined the default extension for jpg (or jpeg or JPG..) images?

Answer (score 25):

All you need to is use ruby's `Hash.invert` method.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804560/1396264) shows how to do it:

> [`Rack::Mime`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Mime.html) has this ability (and Rack is a dependency of Rails):
>
> ```
> require 'rack/mime'
> Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert['image/jpeg']  #=> ".jpg"
> ```
>
> You may wish to memoize the inverted hash if you’re going to do the lookup often, as it’s not an inexpensive operation.

From your tags, it seems you are using rails anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### MimeMagic

In addition to the above answers, I personally like using [`MimeMagic`](https://github.com/minad/mimemagic).

```
require 'mimemagic'
MimeMagic.new('image/jpeg').extensions.first #=> 'jpg'
# Note that this does not include the dot (.) in the extension.
```

### TL;DR;

Other possible useful functions of MimeMagic

```
MimeMagic.new('image/jpeg').image? #=> true
MimeMagic.by_magic('<?xml version="1.0" ?><test></test>').type #=> 'application/xml'
MimeMagic.by_extension('.html').type #=> 'text/html'
```

I recently moved from `Rack::Mime` to `MimeMagic` because I also try to detect from file content what the Mime Type is. To make sure this is reverse compatible, I need to use MM for all directions of conversion:

- content > Mime Type
- Mime Type > Extension
- Extension > Mime Type

#### Different results

The main reason why I switched was a difference when translating `application/xml` to an extension:

```
MimeMagic.new('application/xml').extensions #=> ["xml", "xbl", "xsd", "rng"]
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert['application/xml'] #=> ".xsl"
```

So suddenly I saw some `xml` files being saved with an `.xsl` extension.