# Rails: how to get a file extension/postfix based on the mime type

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mime-types, file-extension

Question I have is, does Ruby on Rails have a function similar to:

```
file_content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(file).first.content_type
```

that will return the file extension or postfix for a specific mime type?  So if I pass in 'image/jpeg' the function will return 'jpg'

Looking for a cleaner way to code than having to write a case statement that does the same job.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`Rack::Mime`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Mime.html) has this ability (and Rack is a dependency of Rails):

```
require 'rack/mime'
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert['image/jpeg']  #=> ".jpg"
```

You may wish to memoize the inverted hash if you’re going to do the lookup often, as it’s not an inexpensive operation.

Answer (score 6):

A better more up to date answer, since I found this googling.

```
Mime::Type.lookup('image/jpeg').symbol.to_s
# => "jpg"
```

Comment: `Mime::Type.lookup` doesn't recognise `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` as being `docx`

Comment: good to know, and to be clear the rack/mime one does, I tested it to verify. So that might be more comprehensive I guess?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActiveStorage, there's a convenience method already provided by Rails, so you don't need to lookup the mime type yourself. For instance, with a Post model that has an attached image:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :image
```

You can use:

```rb
post_instance.image.blob.filename.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcel can be your options too.
It is shipped with Rails (ActiveStorage gem).

https://github.com/rails/marcel

It has hash of MimeType tables into extensions.

You do not have to invert hashes yourself. It might be memory friendly.

Please be aware that its constant is private and may change in future versions.

https://github.com/rails/marcel/blob/main/lib/marcel/tables.rb#L1261

```
iirb(main):008:0> Marcel::TYPES["image/jpeg"]
=>
[["jpg", "jpeg", "jpe", "jif", "jfif", "jfi"],
 [],
 "Joint Photographic Experts Group"]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Marcel](https://github.com/rails/marcel) has ordered lists of [extensions by mime type](https://github.com/rails/marcel/blob/v1.0.2/lib/marcel/tables.rb#L1261):

```
Marcel::TYPES[mime_type][0][0]
```